# javascript: name of ID from element itself

Tags: javascript

a function gets an element from an onclick via somefunction(this)

can the function somehow figure out what the name of the ID for 'this' is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `this` points to the desired element, then `this.id` returns the id attribute for that element as in `<div id="header">` (this would fetch `"header"`).

If what you want is the `name` attribute as in `<input name="address">`, you can get that with `this.name`.

Answer (score 2):

Dos something like

```
alert(this.id);
```